# Is there a way to pass in a database into a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure:

```
create procedure testProc
   declare @databaseId varchar(5)
as
begin
    select columnA 
    from @databaseId.dbo.tableA;
end
```

Is there a way to do this without converting everything into dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes, but you have to use dynamic sql.

Comment: No, there's no other way than using *dynamic SQL* for this - database, table and columns names *cannot* be parametrized in standard T-SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

In this stored procedure pass table name. It should be return all column of passing table.

```
create procedure testProc
   @databaseId varchar(100)
as
begin
   Declare @query varchar(500)
   set @query ='select * from'+ @databaseId;
   EXECUTE(@query)
end
```

Comment: `@databaseId` corresponds to database name only. check the question again.

Comment: In this parameter to pass this type of value ex:@databaseName.dbo.Tablename;

Comment: If you passing only database name then change query only 'select * from'+ @databaseId+'.dbo.table1';

Comment: That should be your answer, However it is something which OP does not want "Is there a way to do this without converting everything into dynamic sql ?"

Comment: @ughai It is depend to user. Here code to specify to convert dynamic sql query create and excute. How can predicat what user want.

Comment: You should use `sp_executesql` instead of just a plain `EXEC`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**

The database name, schema name, table name and column name cannot be assign by a variable in the query.